# Lldb error when trying to init a subclass

Tags: swift

I have a class, ECGView, with a subclass, InjuryView. When I run the code, the console says "lldb" and the following error gets thrown at the init method for the InjuryView subclass: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

I'm relatively new to programming, and I'm having trouble figuring out why this error is being thrown. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
class ECGView {
    var title: String
    var normalImage: UIImage
    var markedImageByComponents: [MarkedAnatomyComponent]
    var steps: [UIImage]
    var stepDescriptions: [String]
    var sectionNames: [[String]]
    var attribution: String
    var injuryList: [[InjuryView]]
    var numberOfPages: Int = 0
    var anatomyOverlay: Bool = false
    var currentStep: Int = 0
    var section: Bool = true

    init(title: String, normalImage: UIImage, markedImageByComponents: [MarkedAnatomyComponent] = [], steps: [UIImage] = [], stepDescriptions: [String] = [], sectionNames: [[String]] = [], attribution: String, injuryList: [[InjuryView]] = []){
        self.title = title
        self.normalImage = normalImage
        self.markedImageByComponents = markedImageByComponents
        self.steps = steps
        self.stepDescriptions = stepDescriptions
        self.sectionNames = sectionNames
        self.attribution = attribution
        self.injuryList = injuryList
    }
}

class InjuryView: ECGView{
    var injuryImage: UIImage
    var injuryComponents: [MarkedAnatomyComponent]
    var injuryTitle: String
    var shortInjuryTitle: String
    var injuryAttribution: String
    var overviewText: String
    var findingsText: String
    var managementText: String
    var otherTitle: String
    var otherText: String
    var normalToggle: Bool = false
}
```

Error thrown here >

```
init(injuryImage: UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Placeholder.jpg"), injuryComponents: [MarkedAnatomyComponent], injuryTitle: String = "", shortInjuryTitle: String = "", injuryAttribution: String, overviewText: String, findingsText: String, managementText: String, otherTitle: String = "", otherText: String = ""){
    self.injuryImage = injuryImage
    self.injuryComponents = injuryComponents
    self.injuryTitle = injuryTitle
    self.shortInjuryTitle = shortInjuryTitle
    self.injuryAttribution = injuryAttribution
    self.overviewText = overviewText
    self.findingsText = findingsText
    self.managementText = managementText
    self.otherTitle = otherTitle
    self.otherText = otherText
    super.init(title: "", normalImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Blank.png"), attribution: "")
    self.title = title
    section = false
}
```

Here's a screenshot if that's more helpful:
[image]

Comment: We're not mind readers; what's the error?

Comment: Sorry, just added it!

Comment: You have shown an error happening when initializing an InjuryView. But no code that you have shown initializes an InjuryView! You need to show us the code that actually causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `init` line:

```
init(title: String, normalImage: UIImage, markedImageByComponents: [MarkedAnatomyComponent] = [], steps: [UIImage] = [], stepDescriptions: [String] = [], sectionNames: [[String]] = [], attribution: String, injuryList: [[InjuryView]] = []){
```

to:

```
init(title: String, normalImage: UIImage, markedImageByComponents: [MarkedAnatomyComponent] = [], steps: [UIImage] = [], stepDescriptions: [String] = [], sectionNames: [[String]] = [[]], attribution: String, injuryList: [[InjuryView]] = [[]]){
```

Because you had this type of array, you need to clear it with `[[]]` instead of `[]`.

Comment: @Nate That is one problem, at least... :p

Comment: I appreciate it-- anything else that you can see?

Comment: @Nate Can you please send a screenshot of the code, with the error? (⌘ + Shift + 4)

Comment: Done! Let me know if that's helpful

Comment: @Nate That is not the way I would reference a `UIImage`, but I am still only about 1 month old to swift so I can't help much more than that, sorry